# How to create a Docking Panel (in the newer version of autodesk forge viewer)

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

Note: I have updated my previous code with the suggestions provided below in the answer.

After following the suggestion, I've found that the docking panel is added to the DOM. But not being displayed(even though z-index is set to 2)

This is what I have tried so far. Also, find the screenshot of the console result below.

````
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, minimum-scale=1.0, initial-scale=1, user-scalable=no" />
        <meta charset="utf-8">

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://developer.api.autodesk.com/modelderivative/v2/viewers/7.*/style.min.css" type="text/css">
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://developer.api.autodesk.com/modelderivative/v2/viewers/7.*/viewer3D.min.js"></script>
        <style>
            body {
                margin: 0;
            }
            #forgeViewer {
                width: 100%;
                height: 100%;
                margin: 0;
                background-color: #F0F8FF;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>

        <div id="forgeViewer"></div>
    </body>
   <script>
   var viewer;

    var options = {
        env: 'AutodeskProduction',
        api: 'derivativeV2',  // for models uploaded to EMEA change this option to 'derivativeV2_EU'
        getAccessToken: function(onTokenReady) {
            var token = 'access token here';
            var timeInSeconds = 3600; // Use value provided by Forge Authentication (OAuth) API
            onTokenReady(token, timeInSeconds);
        }
    };
    SimplePanel = function(parentContainer, id, title, content, x, y)
{
  this.content = content;
Autodesk.Viewing.UI.DockingPanel.call(this, parentContainer, id, title,{shadow:false});

// Auto-fit to the content and don't allow resize.  Position at the coordinates given.
//
this.container.style.height = "150px";
this.container.style.width = "450px";
this.container.style.resize = "auto";
this.container.style.left = x + "px";
this.container.style.top = y + "px"; 
this.container.style.zIndex = 2;

};

SimplePanel.prototype = Object.create(Autodesk.Viewing.UI.DockingPanel.prototype);
SimplePanel.prototype.constructor = SimplePanel;

SimplePanel.prototype.initialize = function()
{ 
        this.title = this.createTitleBar(this.titleLabel || this.container.id);
this.container.appendChild(this.title);

this.container.appendChild(this.content);
this.initializeMoveHandlers(this.container);

this.closer = this.createCloseButton();
this.title.appendChild(this.closer);


var op = {left:false,heightAdjustment:45,marginTop:0};
this.scrollcontainer = this.createScrollContainer(op);

var html = [
    '<div class="uicomponent-panel-controls-container">',
    '<div class="panel panel-default">',
    '<table class="table table-hover table-responsive" id = "clashresultstable">',
    '<thead>',
    '<th>Name</th><th>Status</th><th>Found</th><th>Approved By</th><th>Description</th>',
    '</thead>',
    '<tbody>',
    '<tr><td>test</td><td>test</td><td>test</td><td>test</td><td>test</td></tr>',
    '<tr><td>test</td><td>test</td><td>test</td><td>test</td><td>test</td></tr>',
    '<tr><td>test</td><td>test</td><td>test</td><td>test</td><td>test</td></tr>',
    '<tr><td>test</td><td>test</td><td>test</td><td>test</td><td>test</td></tr>',
    '<tr><td>test</td><td>test</td><td>test</td><td>test</td><td>test</td></tr>',
    '<tr><td>test</td><td>test</td><td>test</td><td>test</td><td>test</td></tr>',
    '<tr><td>test</td><td>test</td><td>test</td><td>test</td><td>test</td></tr>',
    '</tbody>',
    '</table>',
    '</div>',
    '</div>'
].join('\n');


$(this.scrollContainer).append(html);

this.initializeMoveHandlers(this.title);
this.initializeCloseHandler(this.closer);        
};
    Autodesk.Viewing.Initializer(options, function() {

    var htmlDiv = document.getElementById('forgeViewer');
    viewer = new Autodesk.Viewing.GuiViewer3D(htmlDiv);
    var startedCode = viewer.start();
    if (startedCode > 0) {
        console.error('Failed to create a Viewer: WebGL not supported.');
        return;
    }

    console.log('Initialization complete, loading a model next...');

});

var documentId = 'urn:urn here';
Autodesk.Viewing.Document.load(documentId, onDocumentLoadSuccess, onDocumentLoadFailure);


function onDocumentLoadSuccess(viewerDocument) {
    var defaultModel = viewerDocument.getRoot().getDefaultGeometry();
    viewer.loadDocumentNode(viewerDocument, defaultModel);
    viewer.addEventListener( Autodesk.Viewing.SELECTION_CHANGED_EVENT, event=>{
        //console.log(viewer.model.getData());
        console.log(viewer.model.getDocumentNode());
        // console.log(SimplePanel.container)
        viewer.getPropertyPanel(true).setVisible(true)
        var content = document.createElement('div');
        var mypanel = new  SimplePanel(NOP_VIEWER.container,'mypanel','My Panel',content);
        mypanel.setVisible(true);
})
}

function onDocumentLoadFailure() {
    console.error('Failed fetching Forge manifest');
}


   </script>
</html>```[![console output for the dom][1]][1]


 [![DOM screenshot on console][1]][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lp1rm.png
````

Comment: Could you solve it? I'm going through the same thing

Answer (score 0):

You'd need to explicitly call `Autodesk.Viewing.UI.DockingPanel.setVisible(true)` to make the panel visible and put in the desired position with the correct `z-index` ahead of overlapping elements in the viewport as well:

```
SimplePanel.container.style.width = width
SimplePanel.container.style.height = height
SimplePanel.container.style.left = left
SimplePanel.container.style.top = top
SimplePanel.container.style.z-index = 2 // or another value to suit the rest of your UI
SimplePanel.setVisible(true)
```

Otherwise you'd notice it's already present in the DOMtree with `display` set to `none` or either rendered outside of the visible viewport (positioned at `top:0,left:0` etc) or behind(blocked by) other elements ...

If the panel still does not appear try to look for relevant console output esp. error messages when you trigger the selection event and check if the panel is already rendered to the DOMtree in the browser's developer tool but somehow still not visible

Comment: Can you correct me with the code sample above?

I tried calling Autodesk.Viewing.UI.DockingPanel.setVisible(true).It's showing it's not a function.

I changed z-index to zIndex - to overcome left-hand assignment error. Still not sure where you are referring to.I am new to Autodesk forge API.

Comment: `this.container.style.height = "150px";
this.container.style.width = "450px";
this.container.style.resize = "auto";
this.container.style.left = x + "px";
this.container.style.top = y + "px"; `

This part does the same right? And `SimplePanel.setVisible(true)` why it's been set if specified `Autodesk.Viewing.UI.DockingPanel.setVisible(true)`
@Bryan Huang

Comment: SimplePanel.container - is returning undefined in the console

Comment: Sorry for annoying with comments. Now I have updated my code as per the suggestion along with a proper screenshot. Hope this makes sense. Can someone help with this by correcting my code? @Bryan Huang