# How to display docking panel in autodesk viewer found hidden?

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

I have been trying to display a custom docking panel on clicking any particular node in the viewer.

Initially followed this doc, https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/viewer/v2/reference/javascript/dockingpanel/

Error - Uncaught TypeError: this.setVisible is not a function at DockingPanel

Followed this StackOverflow solution,
[How to create a Docking Panel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41543507/how-to-create-a-docking-panel)

This time no error but panel doesn't appear. So raised this issue and got a suggestion to explicitly call and set dimensions for the panel.

[How to create a Docking Panel (in the newer version of autodesk forge viewer)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61380546/how-to-create-a-docking-panel-in-the-newer-version-of-autodesk-forge-viewer)

But the issue has been messed up with repeated edits and unclear modification. Thus raising it here again with more details. So that I could get proper help.

The custom docking panel is being created and added to the DOM. I can find them with all the dimensions specified in the DOM,z-index also set to 2.But still have a problem in showing up.

I'll attach the link for the screenshot - showing the mypanel part being added and the CSS attached.

[![Console screenshot][1]][1] https://i.stack.imgur.com/MwcD7.png

Below is my implementation,

````
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, minimum-scale=1.0, initial-scale=1, user-scalable=no" />
        <meta charset="utf-8">

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://developer.api.autodesk.com/modelderivative/v2/viewers/7.*/style.min.css" type="text/css">
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://developer.api.autodesk.com/modelderivative/v2/viewers/7.*/viewer3D.min.js"></script>
        <style>
            body {
                margin: 0;
            }
            #forgeViewer {
                width: 100%;
                height: 100%;
                margin: 0;
                background-color: #F0F8FF;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="forgeViewer"></div>
    </body>
   <script>
   var viewer;

    var options = {
        env: 'AutodeskProduction',
        api: 'derivativeV2',  // for models uploaded to EMEA change this option to 'derivativeV2_EU'
        getAccessToken: function(onTokenReady) {
            var token = 'eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsImtpZCI6Imp3dF9zeW1tZXRyaWNfa2V5In0.eyJzY29wZSI6WyJidWNrZXQ6Y3JlYXRlIiwiYnVja2V0OnJlYWQiLCJkYXRhOnJlYWQiLCJkYXRhOndyaXRlIl0sImNsaWVudF9pZCI6Ikp2Vk40bzdBQ0V0ZE81TVpnZ21QMk9WM1RoNFJnRW54IiwiYXVkIjoiaHR0cHM6Ly9hdXRvZGVzay5jb20vYXVkL2p3dGV4cDYwIiwianRpIjoic1c2N2R1MUFrS2JTbVp0bEVPb2F5TVNmSjRGSUthcWV2cUxEcFAyU0VkYlZrd1lRYTdTR2JacWc4NUZzWUVPaiIsImV4cCI6MTU4NzY1NDA4M30.zt7dAGOS58TEzyWKyA-Y6YiLGsRNWTy6fcIPLiaCCM4';
            var timeInSeconds = 3600; // Use value provided by Forge Authentication (OAuth) API
            onTokenReady(token, timeInSeconds);
        }
    };
    SimplePanel = function(parentContainer, id, title, content, x, y)
{
  this.content = content;
Autodesk.Viewing.UI.DockingPanel.call(this, parentContainer, id, title,{shadow:false});

// Auto-fit to the content and don't allow resize.  Position at the coordinates given.
//
this.container.style.height = "150px";
this.container.style.width = "450px";
this.container.style.resize = "auto";
this.container.style.left = x + "px";
this.container.style.top = y + "px"; 
this.container.style.zIndex = 2;

};

SimplePanel.prototype = Object.create(Autodesk.Viewing.UI.DockingPanel.prototype);
SimplePanel.prototype.constructor = SimplePanel;

SimplePanel.prototype.initialize = function()
{ 
        this.title = this.createTitleBar(this.titleLabel || this.container.id);
this.container.appendChild(this.title);

this.container.appendChild(this.content);
this.initializeMoveHandlers(this.container);

this.closer = this.createCloseButton();
this.title.appendChild(this.closer);


var op = {left:false,heightAdjustment:45,marginTop:0};
this.scrollcontainer = this.createScrollContainer(op);

var html = [
    '<div class="uicomponent-panel-controls-container">',
    '<div class="panel panel-default">',
    '<table class="table table-hover table-responsive" id = "clashresultstable">',
    '<thead>',
    '<th>Name</th><th>Status</th><th>Found</th><th>Approved By</th><th>Description</th>',
    '</thead>',
    '<tbody>',
    '<tr><td>test</td><td>test</td><td>test</td><td>test</td><td>test</td></tr>',
    '<tr><td>test</td><td>test</td><td>test</td><td>test</td><td>test</td></tr>',
    '<tr><td>test</td><td>test</td><td>test</td><td>test</td><td>test</td></tr>',
    '<tr><td>test</td><td>test</td><td>test</td><td>test</td><td>test</td></tr>',
    '<tr><td>test</td><td>test</td><td>test</td><td>test</td><td>test</td></tr>',
    '<tr><td>test</td><td>test</td><td>test</td><td>test</td><td>test</td></tr>',
    '<tr><td>test</td><td>test</td><td>test</td><td>test</td><td>test</td></tr>',
    '</tbody>',
    '</table>',
    '</div>',
    '</div>'
].join('\n');


$(this.scrollContainer).append(html);

this.initializeMoveHandlers(this.title);
this.initializeCloseHandler(this.closer);        
};
    Autodesk.Viewing.Initializer(options, function() {

    var htmlDiv = document.getElementById('forgeViewer');
    viewer = new Autodesk.Viewing.GuiViewer3D(htmlDiv);
    var startedCode = viewer.start();
    if (startedCode > 0) {
        console.error('Failed to create a Viewer: WebGL not supported.');
        return;
    }

    console.log('Initialization complete, loading a model next...');

});

var documentId = 'urn:dXJuOmFkc2sub2JqZWN0czpvcy5vYmplY3Q6ZmFjaWxpb25ld2NsaWVudGJ1Y2tldC9yYWNfYWR2YW5jZWRfc2FtcGxlX3Byb2plY3QucnZ0';
Autodesk.Viewing.Document.load(documentId, onDocumentLoadSuccess, onDocumentLoadFailure);


function onDocumentLoadSuccess(viewerDocument) {
    var defaultModel = viewerDocument.getRoot().getDefaultGeometry();
    viewer.loadDocumentNode(viewerDocument, defaultModel);
    viewer.addEventListener( Autodesk.Viewing.SELECTION_CHANGED_EVENT, event=>{
        //console.log(viewer.model.getData());
        console.log(viewer.model.getDocumentNode());
        // console.log(SimplePanel.container)
        // viewer.getPropertyPanel(true).setVisible(true)
        var content = document.createElement('div');
        var mypanel = new  SimplePanel(NOP_VIEWER.container,'mypanel','My Panel',content);
        mypanel.setVisible(true);
})
}

function onDocumentLoadFailure() {
    console.error('Failed fetching Forge manifest');
}


   </script>
</html> ```


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/MwcD7.png
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like I suggested in my other answer try set the positioning right as well (left and top etc) in the styling/CSS for the panel and that bit appears to be missing from your code to initialize the panel ...:

```
    var mypanel = new  SimplePanel(NOP_VIEWER.container,'mypanel','My Panel',content); // x,y are not being set.
        mypanel.setVisible(true);
```

Looks like in your screenshot the panel is getting rendered outside of the viewport with invalid coordinate values ...

Comment: How can we get the unique id(dbid) for a particular node?

I tried a few but still not getting something unique for the node on click.

Followed this one - https://adndevblog.typepad.com/cloud_and_mobile/2016/01/view-and-data-api-tips-conversion-between-dbid-and-node.html

But it says dbId is not defined.

I retrieved the guid using `viewer.model.getDocumentNode().data.guid` but that seems to be the same for all nodes whichever I click.

Any help on this @Bryan Huang

Comment: I am getting an id unique for the selection on 
`viewer.getSelection()`

Is this correct? Just noting here such that it could help someone.